# Adding to a Scrollable Panel with Location

Tags: c#, .net, user-controls, panel

I am using a `Panel` to hold a list of controls (user-defined). The way that I add the panels, I am setting the location of the control based on the `Panel.Controls.Count` before I add it to the panel.

```
comRec.Location = new Point(comRec.Location.X, panel1.Controls.Count * 25);
panel1.Controls.Add(comRec);
```

Now, this works nicely and looks exactly the way that I want it to. However, once we reach the limit on the window, the `AutoScroll` enables (which I do want). Now, if the user were to scroll to the bottom of the `Panel`, this ultimately changes the location of every control in the panel. Instead of my first `comRec.Location` being (0,0), it is something like (0,-219). So now, when the user adds another `comRec` object, it creates a HUGE gap between the objects.

My question is this, what is the best way to account for the changes of the location with the scrollbar and still using my adding system. I am assuming that will have to do something with checking the value of the scrollbar and using it to determine the location.

Also, is there a BETTER way to display a list of controls? Should I be using a `Panel`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Look at the [FlowLayoutPanel](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.flowlayoutpanel.aspx) control, it's exactly what you what.

Comment: This looks like it does the trick! However, the FlowDirection Property is a little confusing. When you turn on the AutoScroll, you need to use LeftToRight instead of TopDown for a vertical scrolling panel.

Comment: The [TableLayoutPanel](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.tablelayoutpanel.aspx) might be worth looking at too.

Comment: Since I already have a usercontrol made and it internally handles all the values, I like that the FlowLayoutPanel is more appropriate for my situation but thanks for the alternative. I will keep both of these in mind during future development.

Comment: @Kyle : Yeah sometimes it's a little confusing (and maybe weird!) but when you know how to use it, it works like a charm! :)

Comment: Well, what I determined that it meant was: TopDown means that when it hits the bottom, it shifts over to the right, causing it to scroll horizontally. LeftToRight will add on the right until it hits the edge of the panel, and then move to bottom, causing it to scroll vertically. Due to the fact that the panel is only wide enough for one of my controls, it works perfectly.

Answer (score 1):

You could add an additional panel into the hierarchy:

```
Outer panel (scrollable)
    Inner panel (not scrollable, resize it whenever you add a control)
        User Defined Control 1
        User Defined Control 2
        User Defined Control 3
        User Defined Control 4
        ...
```

This way, your additional controls' locations would be relative to their direct parent, the non-scrolling panel.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, this DOES work, however the FlowLayoutPanel does a cleaner and better job than just using Panels.

Answer (score 1):

If you add several controls, try to suspend the layout of the panel while adding the controls:

```
panel1.SuspendLayout();
// Add controls ...
panel1.ResumeLayout();
```

This helped me in a similar situation where the user could change dynamically the visibility of existing controls.